# node exec command doesn't run under pm2

Tags: node.js, ssh, exec, pm2

I have a very simple node script that waits for an event and then runs an ssh command:

```
    function buildSite(){     
         exec('/usr/bin/ssh user@server \' cd SiteDir; ./build.sh \' ', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log(stdout)
}); }
```

If the app is running with nodemon, this works. If I start the app with PM2, I get an event that tells me the command was received, but the site wasn't rebuilt as expected.

Am I missing something and need to accommodate for PM2?